# Is it possible to use full width adaptive cards in a carousel on Microsoft Teams?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm using

- Microsoft Teams
- Adaptive Cards 1.4
- Node.js Bot Framework SDK 4.14.1

I tried the following URL sample with the full-width property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#example-of-a-carousel-collection

But, the property doesn't work.

Is this possible?

My code:

```
await context.sendActivity({
      attachmentLayout: "carousel",
      attachments: [
        {
          "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
          "content": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.4",
            "msteams": {
              "width": "Full"
            },
            "body": [
              {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "size": "extraLarge",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "Welcome to Employee Connect",
                    "height": "stretch"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "size": "medium",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "Add events to your calendar",
                    "height": "stretch"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "The bot can send \r\rnotification to remind \r\ryou about the latest \r\revents and trainings.",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "height": "stretch"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                      {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "items": [],
                        "height": "stretch"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                      {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "items": [],
                        "height": "stretch"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "actions": [
              {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Let's get started"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
          "content": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.4",
            "msteams": {
              "width": "Full"
            },
            "body": [
              {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "size": "large",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "Employee connect"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "The bot can send notifications \r\rto remind you about the latest \r\r events and training",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "maxWidth": 2
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                      {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "items": [],
                        "height": "stretch"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                      {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "items": [],
                        "height": "stretch"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "actions": [
              {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Let's get started"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
          "content": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.4",
            "msteams": {
              "width": "Full"
            },
            "body": [
              {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "size": "large",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "Employee Connect final"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "Create and manage your tasks",
                    "wrap": true
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "The app identifies all your pending tasks \r\r and helps you manage everything at \r\r one place.",
                    "wrap": true
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "Try these commands \r\r- Pending Submissions \r\r- Pending Approvals- My Tools",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "height": "stretch"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "actions": [
              {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Let's get started"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
    });
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Microsoft Teams support only Adaptive Card version 1.2 and I don't think the above version 1.4 will workout in MS teams ( check the version error messages in https://adaptivecards.io/designer/ ). Try with 1.2 version because as per the latest feature update full-width feature will support for all kind of adaptive card.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to 1.2 and tried again. But the result is the same.

Comment: Teams platform does support 1.4 according to the documentation from Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#adaptive-card

Answer (score 1):

We tried to repro this at our end on web client and we were able to use [full width adaptive cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#full-width-adaptive-card) in a carousel.

However we see the above issue is repro'ing on desktop, adaptive card is not shown in full width. We have raised it internally.

Desktop : [image]
Web client: [image]

Comment: Thanks. I realized that the full-width property works when there is only one adaptive card in the carousel, and the full-width property is disabled when there are multiple adaptive cards. Please try again.

Comment: Are you trying this on desktop? We have checked this on web client previously and it was working fine but on desktop, adaptive card is not shown in full width.  
Desktop :  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfVaq.png  
Web Client :  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwTB4.png

Comment: Also, Could you please confirm if this is working fine on web client?

Comment: I confirmed. Web client works, but windows client doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. We are raising this issue internally.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT: any update on the issue you raised internally? do you have a public link to the issue that we could follow? Thanks.

Comment: currently we do not have any ETA to share. That issue raised is internal and cannot be shared publicly. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT We are also facing the same issue!

Comment: @decoy - We got an update from the engineering team that they are deploying a hotfix to make the carousel width aligning with the older version. however, "full width" flag in carousel adaptive cards will be taken care later. Hence we do not have any ETA to share. I will keep you posted if there is any update.

Comment: by when this will be available? @Meghana-MSFT

Comment: @MoblizeIT -  Full width adaptive cards in a carousel will be taken care later. We do not have ETA to share.

Comment: well i meant by when the hotfix  will be available that will bring older behavior or large width cards in carousel?

Comment: Currently we do not have exact ETA to share for the hotfix.

Comment: The hot fix has been deployed. We tested and its rendering fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ianZq.png

Comment: This issue has been fixed and we have verified the fix. Attaching a screenshot of carousel cards with and without full width. Could you please check once and confirm the fix?

![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/81138249/161036134-c0ea1e8e-cf18-4e3f-9d61-72368dad297b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've **reported** this issue a while ago **to Microsoft**, something about the same time this topic was created. They've done a hotfix to have it aligned with an older version (?) but will fix the actual issue later on. **You can track it on the following URL** where they keep us updated:

**https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/4394**

*(I couldn't just add a reply because my reputation is not high enough yet.)*